# Example of a function $f$ on $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is not $X$-measurable but $|f|$, and $f^2$ are measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**

The following is from Bartle:

Give an example of a function $f$ on $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$  which is not $X-$measurable but is such that $|f|,$ and $f^2$ are measurable.

**Relavant Information**

A family $\textbf{X}$ of subsets of $X$ is a $\sigma$ algebra in case:

1. $\phi, \mathbb{R} \in \textbf{X}$
2. $X \setminus A \in \textbf{X}$ if $A \in \textbf{X}$
3. If $(A_n) \in \textbf{X}$, then the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \textbf{X}$

   Any set in $\textbf{X}$ is called $X-$ measurable.

A function is $X-$ measurable if for every real $\alpha$, the set $\{x \in X : f(x)>\alpha\}$ belongs to $\textbf{X}$

**Attempt**

Consider the following function:
$$f=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{ if} \ x \not\in\mathbb{Q} \\
                  -1 &\mbox{ if} \ x \in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{cases}$$
defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $\textbf{X}$ being the Borel algebra (the $\sigma$ algebra generated by all open intervals $(a,b)$)
Then if $\alpha \in [-1,1)$, the set $\{x: f(x)>\alpha\}$ consists of the irrational numbers. If I can show that the irrationals are not in the Borel Algebra, then I would be done since $|f|=f^2$ is a constant and easily shown to be measurable. **Unfortunately I do not know how to show that the irrationals are not in the Borel Algebra.**

**Edit** it has been brought to my attention that the irrationals are in the Borel algebra. I think this is because the rationals, being countable, can be shown to be in the Borel algebra by constructing appropriate small neighborhoods around each rational and then taking the intersections. **I now seek to construct a set that is not in the Borel algebra**

Alternatively I have tried to define a set other than the irrationals that is not in the Borel Algebra and define a similar function but to no avail. I am currently self studying this book so it would be of great help to me if the answer could contain heuristics on how to tell when a set if borel measurable (although I do not require this in the answer).

Comment: The set of irrationals is in the borel sets.

Comment: Ahhh and here I was so sure that it was not. Would you elaborate on why it is in the Borel algebra? It is perhaps because $\mathbb{Q}\in B$ so the complement is as well?

Comment: The rationals are a countable union of closed sets (points) which are each Borel so the union is Borel and the complement is Borel, with the complement being the irrationals.

Comment: Vitali sets are usually a good prototype for non-measurable sets.  Consider the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Then the equivalence classes generated by this relation are countable, but uncountably many in number.  Pick one element from each equivalence class and you get an unmeasurable set.

Comment: With examples like these, don't jump to crazy sets like the Vitali sets. Nonmeasurable subsets of the real numbers take a lot of work to construct. It is more enlightening and "low leveled" to consider trivial counterexamples.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks, duly noted and edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X=\{a,b\}$. Let $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, X\}$. Define $f(a)=1$, $f(b)=-1$. Then $f^{-1}(1)=\{a\}\notin \Sigma$. But for any set, $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$,  $(f^2)^{-1}(S)=X$ or $\emptyset$ which are measurable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Answer:
```

Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$  and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
\begin{equation*}
 f_A(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}
 1 &\text{if}& x\in A,\\
 -1 &\text{if}& x\notin A.
 \end{array}\right. 
 \end{equation*}
Then, for $-1\leq \alpha<1$ the set $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}~|~f_A(x)>\alpha\}=A$$ which is not measurable and hence $f_A$ is not measurable, but $|f_A|$ is the constant function which is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Set $X= \mathbb R$ with the following sigma algebra $T=\{\emptyset, \mathbb R, (-\infty, 0], (0,\infty)\}$.

Now consider $f:X\to \mathbb R$ defined as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1, x\in (-\infty, 0]\\
-1, x\in (0,1)\\
1, x\in [1,\infty)\end{cases}$$

$|f|=f^2$ are the constant maps having value $1$ at every $x\in X$ hence T-measurable.

$f$ however is not measurable: indeed $f^{-1}((0.1, 1.2))=(-\infty, 0]\cup [1,\infty)\not\in T.$